# Hurricane/Cyclone movement direction

Tags: meteorology, tropical-cyclone

I know that, hurricanes/cyclones move from east to west because they are caught up in the trade winds, which blow from east to west near the equator. Once a hurricane/cyclone moves north of about 30 latitude, they frequently curve, and often do move from west to east. Today I opened windy.com and found that [one hurricane](https://www.windy.com/-Hurricane-tracker/hurricanes/gabrielle?-32.085,155.186,3) close to equator moves from west to east my question is next: what affects this movement from west to east?

[image]

Comment: You need to look at the layer mean steering wind - At the moment over that area the layer mean steering wind is westerly - https://tropic.ssec.wisc.edu/real-time/austeast/winds/wgmsdlm5.GIF. That cyclone may be transition from a tropical one to extratropical one. You need to look whether it is cold core or warm core - available here - https://moe.met.fsu.edu/cyclonephase/